# C++ linux bluetooth sdp_connect only succeed with root privilege

Tags: c++, linux, bluetooth, sdp

I'm trying to run a bluetooth server program on Linux
In order for my client device to find the server, I need to register my service profile on sdp
My code is basically similar to code on [this page](https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x604.html)

The problem is that I need to get root privilege in order to make `sdp_connect` succeed
When running as a normal user, `sdp_connect` always returns `NULL`

Because the other part of my code requires a normal user (not root) environment, I'm wondering if I can make `sdp_connect` and the following `sdp_record_register` succeed without root access

#### Update

Just found a possible solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1065159)
I'm using Bluez5 and `sdp_connect` seems to be deprecated Bluez4 function, so I need to run the service in compatibility mode
Now it works, and it gives access of `/var/run/sdp` to all
Just not sure if it is safe to give such permanent access

Comment: Can you provide a [minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It would help to understand. There's a lot of code in the page you posted.

Comment: "without root access", probably not, or you'll be leaving your system open to super easy hacking. It's not clear where you're doing this. From the cmd-line, can you do `sudu /path/to/my/bluetoothServer` which would grant you temporary root privileges(ish)? Good luck!

Comment: @Pipetus the code in section 4.4.2 and 4.4.3 is already in its simplest form. Basically what it does is setting up a Bluetooth rfcomm profile and connect to sdp and register it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you rightly note, there have been 8 tools [marked as deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) as they are no longer maintained or have been replaced by other tools.

Running with `--compat` would seem like a quick fix rather than a long term solution.

The supported APIs are [Bluetooth Management](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mgmt-api.txt) API which is focused towards system level functions.

The application level is accessed through D-Bus and is spread over several documents in https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

[Adapter](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt), [Device](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt), [GATT](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt), and [profile](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/profile-api.txt) are some of the common ones depending what you are trying to do.

Looking at the `bluetoothctl` [source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/client/main.c#n2900) can give some examples of how to use these APIs with C.

There are more examples in the test directory but they are in Python:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test

Comment: Thanks ukBaz. D-Bus should be right way to go. I'll learn more about the new API.